# R Studio - How to compute Matthews Correlation Coefficient in R?

Tags: r

I used mcc() package in R, but

```
install.packages("mcc")
library("mcc")
library(mcc)
Error in mcc(df$obs, df$pred) : could not find function "mcc"
```

Is there any way to solve this issue? I want to use the built-in package if R has one.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: You may be thinking of the [mccr package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mccr/mccr.pdf)

```
require(mccr)

mccr(act,pred)
```

---

I don't know of a Matthew's Correlation Coefficient package in R, perhaps you mean a function? There are many packages with Matthew's Correlation Coefficient functions. There is an [MCC (Moment Corrected Correlation) package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mcc/mcc.pdf) but I don't think this is what you mean.

For example, the Matthew's Correlation Coefficient function in the `ModelMetrics` package is very useful. See below for an example of its use.

```
predict <- runif(100)
actual <- round(runif(100),0)

head(predict,10)
 [1] 0.14691841 0.01716239 0.12020322 0.71360124 0.77239660 0.96319532 0.47541887
 [8] 0.52121305 0.01268437 0.81935051
head(actual,10)
 [1] 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

```
require(ModelMetrics) 

mcc(predicted = predict,
    actual = actual,
    cutoff = 0.5)

[1] 0.1822204
```

The package allows you to specify a cut-off for classification. See the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ModelMetrics/ModelMetrics.pdf) for further details.

Comment: The mltools package also contains a mcc function to calculate Matthew's correlation coefficient

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue initially and it was something pretty silly! When I googled 'Matthew's Correlation Coefficient in R', the first hit took me to a [page on the mcc function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mltools/versions/0.3.5/topics/mcc). When I installed and loaded the mcc library, it didn't have an mcc function, just like you found.

The issue is that, like A_murphy said, the mcc function is actually in the 'mtools' package, not the 'mcc' package. If you install and load mtools, you should be able to use mcc. Or, as A_Murphy pointed out, you could use the mccr package.